# Computing $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Compute the integral $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx$$

I saw the above question in an Integration bee, and the answer given for the above problem is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, which I don't understand. I did the following:  $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}+\lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\delta}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx$$
which is $\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)$, this implies that the integral does not exist. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't understand ' this implies that the integral does not exist'.You have done it correctly..

Comment: The answer that they have given is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, and a few people getting this question correct in the tournament.

Comment: @Sam Which tournament is this from ?

Comment: @Krosin just a college tournament. Not any famous ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from where where you left:

> $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{-}}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}\frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx+\lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\int_{\delta}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx$

$=\frac{\pi}{2}+\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{-}}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)-\lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}=-\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: This is optimal, as (a) it carefully uses the right definition of the impropert integral and (b) you never have to (incorrectly) invoke the FTC for a function that doesn't even have a $y$-coordinate at $0$.

Comment: @Randall: Except that all the implication arrows should be equals signs.

Comment: @HansLundmark I have edited my answer to correct the error

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{-1}{x^2}=\frac{-1}{1+x^2}$$
so that
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{-1}{1+x^2}\,dx = -\left(\arctan(1)-\arctan(-1)\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Note that there is a pitfall lurking here: if we naively use the fundamental theorem of calculus and write
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\, dx = \left[\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]_{-1}^1=\arctan(1)-\arctan(-1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
then we get the wrong answer. This is because while it is true that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\frac{-1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous everywhere (so that the fundamental theorem applies to it), $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is *not* an antiderivative on the whole of $[-1,1]$: it is not even continuous there, since at $0$ its one-sided limits differ.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late this answer but I thought it's worth mentioning it.

Using symmetry it's possible to circumvent any splitting of the integral at $x=0$.

\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx
& \stackrel{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right)= -\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{ =} & 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx \\
& = & 2\left(\frac{ \pi}{4}-\frac{ \pi}{2}\right) \\
& = & -\frac{ \pi}{2} 
\end{eqnarray*}